# How to choose different initialization strategy for Spring Beans?

Tags: spring, javabeans, lifecycle

Default bean initialization strategy is captured in this log:

```
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread main, Class is.test.spring.Instance> setBeanName() asda
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread main, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsa, message: create()
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread main, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsa, message: start()
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread main, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsaa, message: create()
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread main, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsaa, message: start()
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread Thread-1, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsaa, message: stop()
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread Thread-1, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsaa, message: destroy()
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread Thread-1, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsa, message: stop()
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread Thread-1, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsa, message: destroy()
```

Bean is considered fully initialized after its start() method is called. Now what I want to do is to initialize all the beans synchronously. No bean would proceed to next initialization step before every other bean completed with its step. Resulting log would look something like this:

```
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread main, Class is.test.spring.Instance> setBeanName() asda
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread main, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsa, message: create()
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread main, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsaa, message: create()
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread main, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsa, message: start()
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread main, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsaa, message: start()
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread Thread-1, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsa, message: stop()
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread Thread-1, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsaa, message: stop()
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread Thread-1, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsa, message: destroy()
[Wed Sep 26 13:10:35 CEST 2012]: <Thread Thread-1, Class is.test.spring.ExecutableImpl> ID: fdsaa, message: destroy()
```

Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

Also, would it be possible to process all initializations (every life-cycle step of every bean) in background threads? I expect that initialization will be quite time-consuming...

Comment: See: [SPR-8767 - Parallel bean initialization during startup](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8767)

Comment: So nothing is done regarding that... I am not that 'fluent' in Spring yet but I believe maybe having custom LifecycleProcessor and BeanPostProcessor for controlling PostConstruct and PreDestroy may provide a solution... Although it would be so much better just to stumble upon an implementation which does all that :) Also I kind of presented two issues I want to solve. It would be completely acceptable not to have parallel initialization right now and only have synchronous one.

Answer (score 0):

*Any ideas on how can I achieve this?*

You can manage the Spring lifecycle by using the `<bean depends-on="..."/>` notation or by using the annotation org.springframework.context.annotation.DependsOn.

*Also, would it be possible to process all initializations (every life-cycle step of every bean) in background threads?*

In the init() or destroy() method of your beans (via InitializingBean/DisposableBean or via PostConstruct/PreDestroy), you can create a different thread in order to initialize/destroy it.

Comment: DependsOn is a dependency on bean level, not on initializing step level (if we may call it like that). Also I am aware that I can run threads myself but I ask about Spring's features which would support it